# Can I create a new object in an object property, based on a constructor on the same object?

Tags: javascript

Is following code valid in JavaScript?

```
var model = {
    var1: "",    
    var3: function() {
       this.someval1=0;      
    },
    var4: new var3(),    
}
```

I know function returns an object. Can we use var4 like object? Code above gives error `"var3 is undefined"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. The following however, is:

```
var model = {
    var1: "",    
    var3: function() {
       this.someval1=0;      
    },
}
model.var4 = new model.var3();
```

Please note that you're most likely doing something wrong. You should describe **[what you're trying to do, in addition to how you're trying to solve it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/166899)**.

Comment: I was creating multiple objects that have almost same properties so I created a function with common properties and thought that function returns an object.

Answer (score 6):

`var3` is a property on `model`, so no, this is not valid, unless there's also a function named `var3` defined elsewhere and is in the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the others that posted. You could do something like this:

```
var model = {
    var1: "",
    var3: (function () {
        return window.var3 = function () {
            this.someval1 = 0;
        }
    })(),
    var4: new var3()
}
```

Comment: what if OP also has a `var3` named variable in global scope

Comment: @Ankit then it gets overrided. ;)